# Como seleccionar el valor máximo de una tabla y su valor relacionado desde otra tabla

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Quiero realizar una consulta usando la información de dos tablas, pc y product; ambas tienen en común el campo model, el resultado que espero obtener es el de el máximo precio para cada fabricante, solo que el dbms de oracle me pide siempre agrupar todos los campos y el resultado del query muestra todos los precios de un fabricante en lugar del precio más alto para cada fabricante.

```
    select a.model as modelo, 
           max(a.price) as precio, 
           b.maker as fabricante
    from pc a , product b
    where a.model = b.model
    group by a.model, b.maker
```

Por otro lado si ejecuto la siguiente consulta con otro dbms, el resultado si es el esperado:

```
select a.maker, a.model , max(b.price)
from product a, PC b
where a.model = b.model
group by maker;
```

---

Comment: Yo sé `mysq`l, pero no sabía que había tanta diferencia con `oracle`, pero creo que vos te estás confundiendo. Podrías mostrar la estructura (esquema) de tus tablas?

Answer (score 0):

> Fíjate que solo quité al **group by** el campo **b.maker**, ya que el agrupado
>   por **modelo** en combinación con **max(a.price)** devuelve un **único registro** por **modelo**

```
select a.model as modelo, 
           max(a.price) as precio, 
           b.maker as fabricante
    from pc a , product b
    where a.model = b.model
    group by a.model
```

Pero **unir** con **where** es antiguo, mejor utiliza **join**:

```
select a.model as modelo, 
           max(a.price) as precio, 
           b.maker as fabricante
    from pc a
    join product b on a.model = b.model
    group by a.model
```

Comment: Responder preguntas realizadas en otro idioma no es bien recibido. El O.P. debe cambiar el idioma de su pregunta, ya que este es el sitio en Castellano de S.O. Mi invitación es que a futuro no respondas preguntas formuladas en otro idioma, y que dejes un comentario al O.P. explicando que debe traducir o reformular su pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Perdón..

Comment: Una disculpa, no sabía que tenía que ser en español, hago la corrección, espero puedan ayudarme. La sugerencia no funciona para sql developer.